# MS Teams Outgoing Webhook Without Mention Possible?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to create a subscription to receive the contents of all new messages sent within a private Team, and so far it appears I have to configure a bot / webhook within Teams (and only messages @mentioned to that bot / webhook will be sent to me), or otherwise use the Graphs API (I can't determine whether the same caveat exists with @mentions).

The use case is to allow members of the Team to post messages, and for my listening application to consume the message contents and take an action (turn on a light, etc.. but external to Teams). I don't anticipate needing to write anything back into the Team.

I found this link in another post: https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2020/01/how-to-use-the-new-webhooks-for-microsoft-teams-channel-chat-messages/

Has anyone successfully been able to subscribe to all messages within a private team for a similar use case?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't say if your using delegate permissions or application permissions.  If it's application permissions you are most likely hitting the protected API requirement.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis

Comment: @N Mennear, To track messages and replies in a channel, you can create a change notification subscription at a channel level. Please follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-changenotifications-chatmessage#subscribe-to-messages-in-a-channel).

Comment: Please let us know does that help clarify.

Comment: @N Mennear, Are you still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge

Copying from @Sridevi comments

To track messages and replies in a channel, you can create a change notification subscription at a channel level. Please follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-changenotifications-chatmessage#subscribe-to-messages-in-a-channel).